# prove that for any prime $p≥3$ the following divisibility holds $p|11…122…233…3…99…9-123456789$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

prove that for any prime $p$ the following divisibility holds:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/1P1RSiUobgAJbbGr9

$p|11…122…233…34…445…556…667…778…899…9-123456789 $

for each different digit of the minuend being used p times.

I tried to  identify a difference, but for that I need to transform it to something that depends on $p$

Comment: What have you tried?  Think about the $1$ digits separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $\underbrace{11\dots1}_p=\frac19\underbrace{99\dots9}_p=\frac{10^p-1}9$. Thus we find that \begin{align*}N_p&:=\underbrace{11\dots1}_p\underbrace{22\dots2}_p3\dots8\underbrace{99\dots9}_p\\&=9\cdot\frac{10^p-1}9+8\cdot\frac{10^p-1}9\cdot10^p+\dots+1\cdot\frac{10^9-1}9\cdot10^{8p}.\end{align*}

In particular, because $123456789=9+8\cdot10^1+\dots+1\cdot10^8$, we have that $$N_p-123456789=\sum_{k=1}^9\left(k\cdot\frac{10^p-1}9\cdot10^{(9-k)p}-k\cdot10^{9-k}\right).$$

Consider each term modulo $p$. We already know that $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ for all $a$, and so the $k$-th term in the sum above is equivalent modulo $p$ to $$k\cdot\frac{10-1}9\cdot10^{9-k}-k\cdot10^{9-k}\equiv0\pmod p.$$

Thus the desired difference is equal to the sum of nine different terms, each divisible by $p$, from which we conclude the result.